# Magento Cart - Remove Excl. Tax Subtotal Only

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, tax

Hi my current cart columns are as below because I want to show including and excluding tax on the cart. However, I don't want to show Inc. and Excl. for the Subtotal section so want to remove the one I bolded.

|  Price Inc. TAX   |   Price Excl. TAX  |   Subtotal Inc. TAX  |  **Subtotal Excl. Tax**  |

In the settings there is only the option to show both at the cart page and so I am stuck as to how to remove just this column!

Any help is REALLY appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the `Subtotal Excl. Tax` on your admin panel go to.

```
System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Shopping Cart Display Settings -> Display Subtotal
```

Change the options to `Including Tax`.
Clear the caches just in case. :)